# ZFS and RAID configuration in a personal virtualization Proxmox 6.2 server

Tags: raid, storage, zfs, proxmox, raid-z

I happen to have this unused computer, and I upgraded its hardware a bit so I can use it as my personal platform for virtualized small servers. I plan to put Proxmox 6.2 on it but, before I install it, I'd like to know if it would be fine to use ZFS as the basic filesystem on all the drives, and what RAID configuration would be preferable. The system has the following hardware:

- [Intel Pentium J2900](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/78868/intel-pentium-processor-j2900-2m-cache-up-to-2-67-ghz.html).
- 8GB of DDR3 RAM.
- 1TB SSD drive.
- 1TB HDD drive.
- External 2TB HDD drive, connected through an USB 3 port.

So, should I use ZFS and a RAID configuration with all the drives of the hardware setup described above? If so, which RAID do you think could be used, RAID-Z maybe? Also, do you happen to know if ZFS can hit the system performance significantly more than, let's say, an ext4 filesystem? I'm fully aware that it'll depend on what I/O load has this platform to deal with, but I'm not experienced with the nuances of ZFS.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some thinking and a bit more reading, I've realized that I'm facing two important problems with the hardware setup described in my question:

1. **Not enough RAM** for both ZFS and the platform's purposes.
2. Storage drives **not adequate** for even the most simple RAID setting.

### *Not enough RAM* for both ZFS and the platform's purposes.

In the only answer to the question [ZFS (RAID-Z1) or “hardware” (RAID 5) on Linux system?](https://superuser.com/questions/916044/zfs-raid-z1-or-hardware-raid-5-on-linux-system), it's indicated the following:

> *"ZFS loves memory and will use as much as you care to give it."*

This made me look for information about the hardware requirements of this filesystem, which you can find [in the OpenZFS faq](https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/Project%20and%20Community/FAQ.html#hardware-requirements). It says 8GB+ *"for the best performance"*, although it also indicates that *"it’s perfectly possible to run with 2GB or less"*. Given this requirement, and understanding the tasks ZFS has to perform, it doesn't seem worthy to compromise even just 1GB of RAM on ZFS to end having a mediocre performance in an already tight hardware configuration.

### Storage drives *not adequate* even for the most simple RAID setting.

There are three very different storage drives in the system, with quite different specs. This is not an ideal setup for a RAID at all, although Proxmox seems to allow the creation of a RAIDZ volume with whatever drives you have available (in my case those would be the HDD ones, since I would use the SSD for Proxmox).

### Conclusion

**I won't use ZFS nor RAID in my setup.** As I've illustrated above, my small server it's not "big" enough to use such technologies on it. Since I'm aiming for a decent performance, I'll use a more simple approach to build the system: SSD for the OS and software, the 1TB HDD drive for data, and the remaining 2TB HDD drive as the external backup unit, all using the ext4 filesystem.